# Deploying Mobile web app on Google Cloud

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, google-app-engine

Hello fellow Developers,

We are developing a mobile web application using AngularJs, NodeJs and MYSQL. Our client wants to deploy the application on Google Cloud. My question is:

1. Is deploying application which is based on above technology stack (AngularJs, NodeJs and MySQL) possible on Google Cloud?
2. Can we use Mysql on Google Cloud or we have to use Google Cloud SQL to store    and retrieve data?
3. Can you share your experience of deploying application on Google Cloud.

Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can definitely deploy any stack to Google Cloud using the Google Compute Engine.

2) Yes, you can manage your own MySQL instance on a Google Compute Engine instance. Cloud SQL has a lot of restrictions, so I wouldn't use for anything non-trivial.

3) From my experience, Google Cloud is not very mature, and hard to use unless you are playing by their rules. We were on Google Cloud for a while, but recently migrated everything to AWS due to many Google-specific issues. Support is minimal, and backlog issues are rarely addressed.